# Identify record editor in Archer GRC

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

Is there a way that I can identify the person who last updated a record within Archer GRC? Should we use a calculated field or set the editor's name with a DDE on a user field somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a `LastModifiedBy` field as one of the default field types that you can choose from the template when building an application.

You can also get this info from the `HistoryLog` field if you add it to your application

Answer (score 1):

A good solution I came up with was to use the `LastModifiedBy` field as @BenH suggested from the Application Builder for each ***Application Level***.  I also added an **Event-Drive** Action to update another date field I created/placed on that level/form so I now can see who updated the record and when.

Additionally, I did this for all levels (I have 3), then on the 1st (Root Level), I placed an additional date field that gets updated/indicates when ANY of the 3 levels are updated.  This is handled by additional code in each of the **Event Actions** on each level, so that the **Actions** update both their own level's date field and the one on the root level.